# Mongoose - dependency in default value definition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have simple Mongoose model:

```
var ExampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullHeight: {
    type: Number
  },
  partHeight: {
    type: Number
  }
});
```

Can I set dependency from `fullHeight` for `partHeight` parameter? Example of desired syntax is here:

```
var ExampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullHeight: {
    type: Number
  },
  partHeight: {
    type: Number,
    default: fullHeight / 2
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can setup a [pre-save middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that does this every time you save

```
ExampleSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.partHeight = this.fullHeight / 2;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var ExampleSchema = new Schema({
    fullHeight:  { type: Number, required: true },
    partHeight:  { type: Number }
});

ExampleSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    if (!this.partHeight){
        this.partHeight = this.fullHeight / 2 ;
    }
    next();
});

mongoose.model('Example', ExampleSchema);
```